# General Solution of transformed canonical form. 2nd order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Okay so I've transformed the PDE. That's fine.

My prof has not given enough examples and I cant find anything on the net for the method he wants me to use to solve the thing..... I don't know how to edit with underscores etc so please....spare me..... 
$$
u_{BB} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial B^2},\\
u_B = \frac{\partial u}{\partial B}.
$$

PDE is transformed into 
$$
u_{BB} = -\frac{B}{2}\left(1+B^2\right)^2
$$

I'm meant to use 
$$
u = ve^{cA + nB},
$$
where v is a function of $A$ and $B$, to eliminate the first derivatives....

I've got no problems with other questions where the transformation = 0..... but this one is equal to 
$$
-\frac{B}{2}\left(1+B^2\right)^2
$$
.... ugh....

So anyway I solve 
$$
u_B =.....\\
u_{BB}= \left(v_{BB} + 2nv_B + n^2v\right)e^{cA + nB} = -\frac{B}{2}\left(1+B^2\right)^2
$$

Now how does the prof expect me to solve this without other examples(Its for marks....)

How do i get rid of the $e^{cA + nB}$ and the$-\frac{B}{2}\left(1+B^2\right)^2$ ???

The transformation 
$$
u_{BB} = -\frac{B}{2}\left(1+B^2\right)^2
$$
is correct since the previous question asks me to transform it to that....

I'm going to sleep, will check to tomorrow. Over this question and google not showing me this method... searched for hours... zzzzzz.

Original PDE, before transformation was 
$$
u_{xx} - 4u_{xy} + 4u_{yy} = -\frac{2y}{\left(1+y^2\right)^2}
$$

$$
A= 2x + y,\\
B = y
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no first derivatives in your transformed partial differential equation. Therefore you can simply integrate twice:
$$ \begin{align*}
u_{BB} &= -\frac{1}{2}( B + 2B^3+B^5) \\
u_B &= -\frac{1}{2}(B^2/2+B^4/2+B^6/6) + f(A) \\
u &= -\frac{1}{2}( B^3/6 + B^5/10 + B^7/42 ) + Bf(A) + g(A),
\end{align*} $$
where $f,g$ are arbitrary functions of $A$.